# querycsv.py cannot use after install

Tags: python, pip

I install querycsv in python. But seems I cannot user it after I install.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiVVz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it by using below commands in cmd

```
pip install querycsv
```

or

```
pip3 install querycsv
```

Also if you want you can download it manually from  [here](https://packaging.python.org/installing/).